# Converting CSV file with polygons in dictionary format into GeoDataFrame

Tags: python, convert, csv, geopandas, dictionary

I have a CSV file with data in below format. I want to read this using Python into a GeoPandas' DataFrame where boundary becomes geometry. I'm not even sure where to begin with.

```
pincode    city        boundary
110001     New Delhi   [{'lat': 28.645049, 'lng': 77.198277}, {'lat': 28.644902, 'lng': 77.198636}, {'lat': 28.644509, 'lng': 77.199509}, {'lat': 28.644121, 'lng': 77.200294}, {'lat': 28.644081, 'lng': 77.200375}, {'lat': 28.644072, 'lng': 77.200398}, {'lat': 28.643946, 'lng': 77.200706}, {'lat': 28.643773, 'lng': 77.201034}, {'lat': 28.643652, 'lng': 77.201326}, {'lat': 28.643326, 'lng': 77.202113}, {'lat': 28.643051, 'lng': 77.202812}, {'lat': 28.642974, 'lng': 77.203038}, {'lat': 28.642957, 'lng': 77.203042}, {'lat': 28.642939, 'lng': 77.203046}, {'lat': 28.642938, 'lng': 77.203046}, {'lat': 28.642904, 'lng': 77.20306}, {'lat': 28.642872, 'lng': 77.203078}, {'lat': 28.642841, 'lng': 77.203101}, {'lat': 28.642813, 'lng': 77.203128}, {'lat': 28.642788, 'lng': 77.20316}, {'lat': 28.642766, 'lng': 77.203195}, {'lat': 28.642741, 'lng': 77.203252}, {'lat': 28.64273, 'lng': 77.203293}, {'lat': 28.642722, 'lng': 77.203336}, {'lat': 28.64272, 'lng': 77.203379}, {'lat': 28.642721, 'lng': 77.203422}, {'lat': 28.642727, 'lng': 77.203465}, {'lat': 28.642714, 'lng': 77.203476}, {'lat': 28.642208, 'lng': 77.203885}, {'lat': 28.6418, 'lng': 77.204208}, {'lat': 28.641751, 'lng': 77.204268}, {'lat': 28.64165, 'lng': 77.204392}, {'lat': 28.641548, 'lng': 77.204517}, {'lat': 28.641419, 'lng': 77.204738}, {'lat': 28.641133, 'lng': 77.205228}, {'lat': 28.640614, 'lng': 77.206148}, {'lat': 28.640608, 'lng': 77.206158}, {'lat': 28.640209, 'lng': 77.206866}, {'lat': 28.639869, 'lng': 77.207467}, {'lat': 28.639591, 'lng': 77.207948}, {'lat': 28.639082, 'lng': 77.208934}, {'lat': 28.638624, 'lng': 77.209698}, {'lat': 28.637515, 'lng': 77.211546}, {'lat': 28.636575, 'lng': 77.213174}, {'lat': 28.636345, 'lng': 77.213604}, {'lat': 28.636171, 'lng': 77.213905}, {'lat': 28.635993, 'lng': 77.214213}, {'lat': 28.635548, 'lng': 77.214964}, {'lat': 28.634743, 'lng': 77.21634}, {'lat': 28.634321, 'lng': 77.217043}, {'lat': 28.63433, 'lng': 77.21705}, {'lat': 28.634399, 'lng': 77.217103}, {'lat': 28.634414, 'lng': 77.217115}, {'lat': 28.63442, 'lng': 77.217119}, {'lat': 28.634514, 'lng': 77.217201}, {'lat': 28.634561, 'lng': 77.217242}, {'lat': 28.634695, 'lng': 77.217374}, {'lat': 28.634803, 'lng': 77.217496}, {'lat': 28.634821, 'lng': 77.217516}, {'lat': 28.634863, 'lng': 77.217569}, {'lat': 28.63494, 'lng': 77.217666}, {'lat': 28.634998, 'lng': 77.217751}, {'lat': 28.635049, 'lng': 77.217825}, {'lat': 28.635151, 'lng': 77.217991}, {'lat': 28.635242, 'lng': 77.218164}, {'lat': 28.635325, 'lng': 77.218343}, {'lat': 28.635397, 'lng': 77.218527}, {'lat': 28.635459, 'lng': 77.218716}, {'lat': 28.63551, 'lng': 77.21891}, {'lat': 28.635551, 'lng': 77.219106}, {'lat': 28.635582, 'lng': 77.219305}, {'lat': 28.635601, 'lng': 77.219506}, {'lat': 28.635609, 'lng': 77.219708}, {'lat': 28.635608, 'lng': 77.219779}, {'lat': 28.635607, 'lng': 77.21986}, {'lat': 28.635606, 'lng': 77.219905}, {'lat': 28.635641, 'lng': 77.219907}, {'lat': 28.6357, 'lng': 77.21991}, {'lat': 28.635792, 'lng': 77.219914}, {'lat': 28.635956, 'lng': 77.219922}, {'lat': 28.635675, 'lng': 77.22104}, {'lat': 28.635632, 'lng': 77.221157}, {'lat': 28.635431, 'lng': 77.221683}, {'lat': 28.636196, 'lng': 77.222265}, {'lat': 28.636403, 'lng': 77.222412}, {'lat': 28.636528, 'lng': 77.222499}, {'lat': 28.637572, 'lng': 77.223245}, {'lat': 28.636794, 'lng': 77.2246}, {'lat': 28.63596, 'lng': 77.226052}, {'lat': 28.635181, 'lng': 77.227409}, {'lat': 28.633703, 'lng': 77.229983}, {'lat': 28.633687, 'lng': 77.230011}, {'lat': 28.632975, 'lng': 77.231229}, {'lat': 28.632533, 'lng': 77.231993}, {'lat': 28.630725, 'lng': 77.235121}, {'lat': 28.630295, 'lng': 77.235864}, {'lat': 28.628896, 'lng': 77.238258}, {'lat': 28.628806, 'lng': 77.238422}, {'lat': 28.628253, 'lng': 77.239422}, {'lat': 28.627821, 'lng': 77.240202}, {'lat': 28.627632, 'lng': 77.240544}, {'lat': 28.627505, 'lng': 77.240714}, {'lat': 28.627345, 'lng': 77.240953}, {'lat': 28.627185, 'lng': 77.241107}, {'lat': 28.627004, 'lng': 77.241164}, {'lat': 28.626479, 'lng': 77.241273}, {'lat': 28.626058, 'lng': 77.240976}, {'lat': 28.625644, 'lng': 77.241703}, {'lat': 28.625362, 'lng': 77.242157}, {'lat': 28.625224, 'lng': 77.242364}, {'lat': 28.625051, 'lng': 77.242598}, {'lat': 28.624772, 'lng': 77.242943}, {'lat': 28.624453, 'lng': 77.243297}, {'lat': 28.624159, 'lng': 77.243608}, {'lat': 28.623799, 'lng': 77.243969}, {'lat': 28.622416, 'lng': 77.24499}, {'lat': 28.621872, 'lng': 77.245377}, {'lat': 28.621419, 'lng': 77.245681}, {'lat': 28.620879, 'lng': 77.245985}, {'lat': 28.620191, 'lng': 77.246274}, {'lat': 28.619254, 'lng': 77.246595}, {'lat': 28.618406, 'lng': 77.246855}, {'lat': 28.616333, 'lng': 77.247535}, {'lat': 28.615878, 'lng': 77.247698}, {'lat': 28.615448, 'lng': 77.247921}, {'lat': 28.615057, 'lng': 77.248204}, {'lat': 28.614618, 'lng': 77.248606}, {'lat': 28.614245, 'lng': 77.249031}, {'lat': 28.613963, 'lng': 77.249455}, {'lat': 28.613734, 'lng': 77.249895}, {'lat': 28.61357, 'lng': 77.250286}, {'lat': 28.613441, 'lng': 77.250673}, {'lat': 28.613412, 'lng': 77.250807}, {'lat': 28.613072, 'lng': 77.250916}, {'lat': 28.613033, 'lng': 77.250928}, {'lat': 28.612716, 'lng': 77.250071}, {'lat': 28.612495, 'lng': 77.249455}, {'lat': 28.612299, 'lng': 77.248911}, {'lat': 28.612296, 'lng': 77.248902}, {'lat': 28.612148, 'lng': 77.248433}, {'lat': 28.61208, 'lng': 77.24812}, {'lat': 28.612071, 'lng': 77.247972}, {'lat': 28.612078, 'lng': 77.247818}, {'lat': 28.612085, 'lng': 77.247709}, {'lat': 28.612102, 'lng': 77.247612}, {'lat': 28.612134, 'lng': 77.247494}, {'lat': 28.612315, 'lng': 77.247077}, {'lat': 28.612367, 'lng': 77.246931}, {'lat': 28.612404, 'lng': 77.24679}, {'lat': 28.612444, 'lng': 77.246595}, {'lat': 28.612468, 'lng': 77.246433}, {'lat': 28.612534, 'lng': 77.245017}, {'lat': 28.612539, 'lng': 77.244911}, {'lat': 28.612613, 'lng': 77.243773}, {'lat': 28.612675, 'lng': 77.24256}, {'lat': 28.612758, 'lng': 77.240614}, {'lat': 28.612766, 'lng': 77.240425}, {'lat': 28.612778, 'lng': 77.240151}, {'lat': 28.611333, 'lng': 77.240062}, {'lat': 28.610746, 'lng': 77.240044}, {'lat': 28.609314, 'lng': 77.240031}, {'lat': 28.609314, 'lng': 77.240013}, {'lat': 28.609315, 'lng': 77.238612}, {'lat': 28.609325, 'lng': 77.238508}, {'lat': 28.609412, 'lng': 77.238023}, {'lat': 28.60947, 'lng': 77.23777}, {'lat': 28.609652, 'lng': 77.236976}, {'lat': 28.609849, 'lng': 77.236465}, {'lat': 28.610252, 'lng': 77.235752}, {'lat': 28.610735, 'lng': 77.234899}, {'lat': 28.610768, 'lng': 77.234608}, {'lat': 28.610768, 'lng': 77.23448}, {'lat': 28.610757, 'lng': 77.234366}, {'lat': 28.610735, 'lng': 77.23411}, {'lat': 28.610727, 'lng': 77.234}, {'lat': 28.61064, 'lng': 77.233835}, {'lat': 28.610168, 'lng': 77.232829}, {'lat': 28.610108, 'lng': 77.232701}, {'lat': 28.609461, 'lng': 77.231316}, {'lat': 28.609453, 'lng': 77.231025}, {'lat': 28.609476, 'lng': 77.230716}, {'lat': 28.609523, 'lng': 77.230455}, {'lat': 28.610259, 'lng': 77.229245}, {'lat': 28.61054, 'lng': 77.228783}, {'lat': 28.61091, 'lng': 77.228072}, {'lat': 28.611073, 'lng': 77.227927}, {'lat': 28.611317, 'lng': 77.22775}, {'lat': 28.61151, 'lng': 77.227662}, {'lat': 28.611669, 'lng': 77.227618}, {'lat': 28.611557, 'lng': 77.227565}, {'lat': 28.611386, 'lng': 77.227468}, {'lat': 28.611255, 'lng': 77.227344}, {'lat': 28.611088, 'lng': 77.227119}, {'lat': 28.610914, 'lng': 77.226863}, {'lat': 28.610029, 'lng': 77.224885}, {'lat': 28.610015, 'lng': 77.224891}, {'lat': 28.609998, 'lng': 77.224899}, {'lat': 28.609966, 'lng': 77.22491}, {'lat': 28.609917, 'lng': 77.224916}, {'lat': 28.609884, 'lng': 77.224915}, {'lat': 28.609851, 'lng': 77.22491}, {'lat': 28.609819, 'lng': 77.224899}, {'lat': 28.609788, 'lng': 77.224885}, {'lat': 28.60976, 'lng': 77.224867}, {'lat': 28.609733, 'lng': 77.224844}, {'lat': 28.60971, 'lng': 77.224819}, {'lat': 28.609689, 'lng': 77.22479}, {'lat': 28.609665, 'lng': 77.224742}, {'lat': 28.609653, 'lng': 77.224708}, {'lat': 28.609645, 'lng': 77.224673}, {'lat': 28.609642, 'lng': 77.224636}, {'lat': 28.609642, 'lng': 77.2246}, {'lat': 28.609647, 'lng': 77.224563}, {'lat': 28.609656, 'lng': 77.224528}, {'lat': 28.609668, 'lng': 77.224494}, {'lat': 28.609684, 'lng': 77.224463}, {'lat': 28.609715, 'lng': 77.22442}, {'lat': 28.60974, 'lng': 77.224395}, {'lat': 28.609767, 'lng': 77.224373}, {'lat': 28.609796, 'lng': 77.224356}, {'lat': 28.609827, 'lng': 77.224343}, {'lat': 28.609859, 'lng': 77.224334}, {'lat': 28.609892, 'lng': 77.224329}, {'lat': 28.609925, 'lng': 77.224329}, {'lat': 28.610004, 'lng': 77.22262}, {'lat': 28.61002, 'lng': 77.222261}, {'lat': 28.610132, 'lng': 77.220028}, {'lat': 28.610207, 'lng': 77.218292}, {'lat': 28.610281, 'lng': 77.216702}, {'lat': 28.610286, 'lng': 77.216493}, {'lat': 28.611924, 'lng': 77.216616}, {'lat': 28.612058, 'lng': 77.21392}, {'lat': 28.612106, 'lng': 77.212641}, {'lat': 28.612043, 'lng': 77.212639}, {'lat': 28.610715, 'lng': 77.212556}, {'lat': 28.6105, 'lng': 77.212547}, {'lat': 28.610512, 'lng': 77.212332}, {'lat': 28.610472, 'lng': 77.212325}, {'lat': 28.610433, 'lng': 77.212312}, {'lat': 28.610396, 'lng': 77.212294}, {'lat': 28.610361, 'lng': 77.212271}, {'lat': 28.610329, 'lng': 77.212243}, {'lat': 28.6103, 'lng': 77.21221}, {'lat': 28.610264, 'lng': 77.212155}, {'lat': 28.610237, 'lng': 77.212092}, {'lat': 28.610225, 'lng': 77.212048}, {'lat': 28.610218, 'lng': 77.212003}, {'lat': 28.610217, 'lng': 77.211957}, {'lat': 28.61022, 'lng': 77.211911}, {'lat': 28.610228, 'lng': 77.211866}, {'lat': 28.610241, 'lng': 77.211822}, {'lat': 28.610259, 'lng': 77.21178}, {'lat': 28.610281, 'lng': 77.211742}, {'lat': 28.610307, 'lng': 77.211706}, {'lat': 28.610336, 'lng': 77.211675}, {'lat': 28.610369, 'lng': 77.211648}, {'lat': 28.610391, 'lng': 77.211635}, {'lat': 28.609223, 'lng': 77.209087}, {'lat': 28.60918, 'lng': 77.209104}, {'lat': 28.609158, 'lng': 77.209111}, {'lat': 28.609114, 'lng': 77.209119}, {'lat': 28.609091, 'lng': 77.20912}, {'lat': 28.609068, 'lng': 77.20912}, {'lat': 28.609045, 'lng': 77.209119}, {'lat': 28.609001, 'lng': 77.209111}, {'lat': 28.608979, 'lng': 77.209104}, {'lat': 28.608957, 'lng': 77.209096}, {'lat': 28.608915, 'lng': 77.209076}, {'lat': 28.608895, 'lng': 77.209064}, {'lat': 28.608876, 'lng': 77.20905}, {'lat': 28.60884, 'lng': 77.209019}, {'lat': 28.608823, 'lng': 77.209001}, {'lat': 28.608793, 'lng': 77.208962}, {'lat': 28.608767, 'lng': 77.20892}, {'lat': 28.608756, 'lng': 77.208897}, {'lat': 28.608746, 'lng': 77.208874}, {'lat': 28.608738, 'lng': 77.20885}, {'lat': 28.60873, 'lng': 77.208826}, {'lat': 28.608724, 'lng': 77.208801}, {'lat': 28.60872, 'lng': 77.208775}, {'lat': 28.608715, 'lng': 77.208724}, {'lat': 28.608715, 'lng': 77.208698}, {'lat': 28.608716, 'lng': 77.208672}, {'lat': 28.608718, 'lng': 77.208646}, {'lat': 28.608727, 'lng': 77.208596}, {'lat': 28.608734, 'lng': 77.208571}, {'lat': 28.608742, 'lng': 77.208547}, {'lat': 28.608751, 'lng': 77.208523}, {'lat': 28.608762, 'lng': 77.2085}, {'lat': 28.608786, 'lng': 77.208457}, {'lat': 28.608815, 'lng': 77.208417}, {'lat': 28.608832, 'lng': 77.208399}, {'lat': 28.608849, 'lng': 77.208382}, {'lat': 28.608867, 'lng': 77.208366}, {'lat': 28.608886, 'lng': 77.208352}, {'lat': 28.607986, 'lng': 77.206205}, {'lat': 28.607816, 'lng': 77.205815}, {'lat': 28.607836, 'lng': 77.2058}, {'lat': 28.607856, 'lng': 77.205784}, {'lat': 28.607875, 'lng': 77.205766}, {'lat': 28.607893, 'lng': 77.205748}, {'lat': 28.60791, 'lng': 77.205728}, {'lat': 28.60794, 'lng': 77.205684}, {'lat': 28.607953, 'lng': 77.205661}, {'lat': 28.607965, 'lng': 77.205637}, {'lat': 28.607976, 'lng': 77.205612}, {'lat': 28.607985, 'lng': 77.205586}, {'lat': 28.607993, 'lng': 77.20556}, {'lat': 28.607999, 'lng': 77.205533}, {'lat': 28.608004, 'lng': 77.205506}, {'lat': 28.608007, 'lng': 77.205479}, {'lat': 28.608009, 'lng': 77.205451}, {'lat': 28.610513, 'lng': 77.20564}, {'lat': 28.610516, 'lng': 77.205593}, {'lat': 28.610524, 'lng': 77.205548}, {'lat': 28.610537, 'lng': 77.205504}, {'lat': 28.610555, 'lng': 77.205462}, {'lat': 28.610577, 'lng': 77.205423}, {'lat': 28.610603, 'lng': 77.205388}, {'lat': 28.610633, 'lng': 77.205356}, {'lat': 28.610666, 'lng': 77.205329}, {'lat': 28.610702, 'lng': 77.205307}, {'lat': 28.61074, 'lng': 77.20529}, {'lat': 28.61078, 'lng': 77.205279}, {'lat': 28.61082, 'lng': 77.205273}, {'lat': 28.610861, 'lng': 77.205273}, {'lat': 28.610901, 'lng': 77.205279}, {'lat': 28.610941, 'lng': 77.20529}, {'lat': 28.610979, 'lng': 77.205307}, {'lat': 28.611015, 'lng': 77.205329}, {'lat': 28.611048, 'lng': 77.205356}, {'lat': 28.611078, 'lng': 77.205388}, {'lat': 28.611104, 'lng': 77.205423}, {'lat': 28.611126, 'lng': 77.205462}, {'lat': 28.611144, 'lng': 77.205504}, {'lat': 28.611157, 'lng': 77.205548}, {'lat': 28.611165, 'lng': 77.205593}, {'lat': 28.611168, 'lng': 77.20564}, {'lat': 28.611167, 'lng': 77.205686}, {'lat': 28.61116, 'lng': 77.205732}, {'lat': 28.611148, 'lng': 77.205776}, {'lat': 28.611131, 'lng': 77.205818}, {'lat': 28.61111, 'lng': 77.205858}, {'lat': 28.611071, 'lng': 77.205911}, {'lat': 28.61104, 'lng': 77.205942}, {'lat': 28.610988, 'lng': 77.205979}, {'lat': 28.611254, 'lng': 77.206569}, {'lat': 28.611436, 'lng': 77.206971}, {'lat': 28.611693, 'lng': 77.207541}, {'lat': 28.612073, 'lng': 77.20839}, {'lat': 28.612184, 'lng': 77.208639}, {'lat': 28.612208, 'lng': 77.208626}, {'lat': 28.612237, 'lng': 77.208616}, {'lat': 28.612266, 'lng': 77.20861}, {'lat': 28.612297, 'lng': 77.208608}, {'lat': 28.612327, 'lng': 77.20861}, {'lat': 28.612356, 'lng': 77.208616}, {'lat': 28.612385, 'lng': 77.208626}, {'lat': 28.612412, 'lng': 77.208641}, {'lat': 28.612438, 'lng': 77.208659}, {'lat': 28.612458, 'lng': 77.208678}, {'lat': 28.613925, 'lng': 77.208774}, {'lat': 28.614147, 'lng': 77.203886}, {'lat': 28.614683, 'lng': 77.203908}, {'lat': 28.614777, 'lng': 77.202106}, {'lat': 28.61479, 'lng': 77.201861}, {'lat': 28.61686, 'lng': 77.20197}, {'lat': 28.617487, 'lng': 77.202041}, {'lat': 28.617489, 'lng': 77.202041}, {'lat': 28.617552, 'lng': 77.200778}, {'lat': 28.617589, 'lng': 77.200036}, {'lat': 28.617595, 'lng': 77.19992}, {'lat': 28.617616, 'lng': 77.199767}, {'lat': 28.617624, 'lng': 77.199704}, {'lat': 28.617625, 'lng': 77.199671}, {'lat': 28.617637, 'lng': 77.199345}, {'lat': 28.617663, 'lng': 77.198643}, {'lat': 28.61885, 'lng': 77.198712}, {'lat': 28.619276, 'lng': 77.198745}, {'lat': 28.620541, 'lng': 77.198823}, {'lat': 28.623049, 'lng': 77.198982}, {'lat': 28.623134, 'lng': 77.198987}, {'lat': 28.623227, 'lng': 77.198965}, {'lat': 28.623441, 'lng': 77.19882}, {'lat': 28.623467, 'lng': 77.198802}, {'lat': 28.623075, 'lng': 77.197927}, {'lat': 28.622854, 'lng': 77.197435}, {'lat': 28.622391, 'lng': 77.196404}, {'lat': 28.622391, 'lng': 77.196403}, {'lat': 28.622199, 'lng': 77.195976}, {'lat': 28.621874, 'lng': 77.195255}, {'lat': 28.621507, 'lng': 77.194471}, {'lat': 28.621489, 'lng': 77.194433}, {'lat': 28.621452, 'lng': 77.194354}, {'lat': 28.621267, 'lng': 77.194036}, {'lat': 28.621245, 'lng': 77.194002}, {'lat': 28.620923, 'lng': 77.19351}, {'lat': 28.620923, 'lng': 77.193509}, {'lat': 28.621756, 'lng': 77.191834}, {'lat': 28.622219, 'lng': 77.191865}, {'lat': 28.622722, 'lng': 77.191604}, {'lat': 28.623039, 'lng': 77.191629}, {'lat': 28.623597, 'lng': 77.191704}, {'lat': 28.624176, 'lng': 77.190495}, {'lat': 28.625751, 'lng': 77.191704}, {'lat': 28.625784, 'lng': 77.192713}, {'lat': 28.62643, 'lng': 77.193311}, {'lat': 28.626375, 'lng': 77.193735}, {'lat': 28.626856, 'lng': 77.194022}, {'lat': 28.627124, 'lng': 77.194425}, {'lat': 28.62958, 'lng': 77.196452}, {'lat': 28.631712, 'lng': 77.197872}, {'lat': 28.632445, 'lng': 77.196676}, {'lat': 28.637159, 'lng': 77.199543}, {'lat': 28.638329, 'lng': 77.200677}, {'lat': 28.641889, 'lng': 77.202113}, {'lat': 28.642438, 'lng': 77.201187}, {'lat': 28.643274, 'lng': 77.19962}, {'lat': 28.643475, 'lng': 77.198416}, {'lat': 28.644089, 'lng': 77.198671}, {'lat': 28.644164, 'lng': 77.198655}, {'lat': 28.644208, 'lng': 77.198672}, {'lat': 28.64429, 'lng': 77.198628}, {'lat': 28.64437, 'lng': 77.198487}, {'lat': 28.64443, 'lng': 77.198335}, {'lat': 28.644625, 'lng': 77.197954}, {'lat': 28.64504, 'lng': 77.198226}, {'lat': 28.645063, 'lng': 77.198241}, {'lat': 28.645049, 'lng': 77.198277}]
110002     New Delhi   [{'lat': 28.663141, 'lng': 77.243549}, {'lat': 28.66299, 'lng': 77.244929}, {'lat': 28.66299, 'lng': 77.245877}, {'lat': 28.662649, 'lng': 77.246868}, {'lat': 28.662082, 'lng': 77.248549}, {'lat': 28.661325, 'lng': 77.251221}, {'lat': 28.660757, 'lng': 77.252687}, {'lat': 28.660379, 'lng': 77.25329}, {'lat': 28.659815, 'lng': 77.253846}, {'lat': 28.659811, 'lng': 77.25385}, {'lat': 28.659243, 'lng': 77.254626}, {'lat': 28.658713, 'lng': 77.255316}, {'lat': 28.657654, 'lng': 77.257126}, {'lat': 28.656178, 'lng': 77.259453}, {'lat': 28.65508, 'lng': 77.260961}, {'lat': 28.653907, 'lng': 77.261996}, {'lat': 28.652658, 'lng': 77.262728}, {'lat': 28.651561, 'lng': 77.263159}, {'lat': 28.651524, 'lng': 77.263177}, {'lat': 28.651031, 'lng': 77.263418}, {'lat': 28.650009, 'lng': 77.263978}, {'lat': 28.648949, 'lng': 77.264409}, {'lat': 28.648344, 'lng': 77.264495}, {'lat': 28.647436, 'lng': 77.264667}, {'lat': 28.6463, 'lng': 77.264839}, {'lat': 28.645354, 'lng': 77.264882}, {'lat': 28.644143, 'lng': 77.264666}, {'lat': 28.643121, 'lng': 77.264192}, {'lat': 28.642554, 'lng': 77.263933}, {'lat': 28.641494, 'lng': 77.263459}, {'lat': 28.640207, 'lng': 77.262899}, {'lat': 28.639147, 'lng': 77.262252}, {'lat': 28.636725, 'lng': 77.260959}, {'lat': 28.634959, 'lng': 77.259864}, {'lat': 28.634568, 'lng': 77.259622}, {'lat': 28.633092, 'lng': 77.258415}, {'lat': 28.630357, 'lng': 77.25784}, {'lat': 28.629583, 'lng': 77.257508}, {'lat': 28.629354, 'lng': 77.257409}, {'lat': 28.628399, 'lng': 77.25613}, {'lat': 28.627415, 'lng': 77.255483}, {'lat': 28.627596, 'lng': 77.25493}, {'lat': 28.628047, 'lng': 77.253557}, {'lat': 28.628044, 'lng': 77.253553}, {'lat': 28.62809, 'lng': 77.252383}, {'lat': 28.628099, 'lng': 77.251774}, {'lat': 28.628091, 'lng': 77.250813}, {'lat': 28.627868, 'lng': 77.250641}, {'lat': 28.627719, 'lng': 77.250544}, {'lat': 28.627545, 'lng': 77.250358}, {'lat': 28.627443, 'lng': 77.250218}, {'lat': 28.627396, 'lng': 77.25006}, {'lat': 28.627365, 'lng': 77.249502}, {'lat': 28.627338, 'lng': 77.249223}, {'lat': 28.6273, 'lng': 77.248982}, {'lat': 28.627217, 'lng': 77.248682}, {'lat': 28.62711, 'lng': 77.248433}, {'lat': 28.626963, 'lng': 77.248159}, {'lat': 28.626783, 'lng': 77.247854}, {'lat': 28.626595, 'lng': 77.247593}, {'lat': 28.626315, 'lng': 77.24733}, {'lat': 28.62626, 'lng': 77.247278}, {'lat': 28.626176, 'lng': 77.247228}, {'lat': 28.625988, 'lng': 77.247209}, {'lat': 28.624856, 'lng': 77.24721}, {'lat': 28.622885, 'lng': 77.247778}, {'lat': 28.622048, 'lng': 77.248047}, {'lat': 28.621106, 'lng': 77.248336}, {'lat': 28.620842, 'lng': 77.248419}, {'lat': 28.619569, 'lng': 77.248819}, {'lat': 28.617678, 'lng': 77.24943}, {'lat': 28.615463, 'lng': 77.250166}, {'lat': 28.615119, 'lng': 77.250265}, {'lat': 28.61437, 'lng': 77.250501}, {'lat': 28.613841, 'lng': 77.25067}, {'lat': 28.613412, 'lng': 77.250807}, {'lat': 28.613441, 'lng': 77.250673}, {'lat': 28.61357, 'lng': 77.250286}, {'lat': 28.613734, 'lng': 77.249895}, {'lat': 28.613963, 'lng': 77.249455}, {'lat': 28.614245, 'lng': 77.249031}, {'lat': 28.614618, 'lng': 77.248606}, {'lat': 28.615057, 'lng': 77.248204}, {'lat': 28.615448, 'lng': 77.247921}, {'lat': 28.615878, 'lng': 77.247698}, {'lat': 28.616333, 'lng': 77.247535}, {'lat': 28.618406, 'lng': 77.246855}, {'lat': 28.619254, 'lng': 77.246595}, {'lat': 28.620191, 'lng': 77.246274}, {'lat': 28.620879, 'lng': 77.245985}, {'lat': 28.621419, 'lng': 77.245681}, {'lat': 28.621872, 'lng': 77.245377}, {'lat': 28.622416, 'lng': 77.24499}, {'lat': 28.623799, 'lng': 77.243969}, {'lat': 28.624159, 'lng': 77.243608}, {'lat': 28.624453, 'lng': 77.243297}, {'lat': 28.624772, 'lng': 77.242943}, {'lat': 28.625051, 'lng': 77.242598}, {'lat': 28.625224, 'lng': 77.242364}, {'lat': 28.625362, 'lng': 77.242157}, {'lat': 28.625644, 'lng': 77.241703}, {'lat': 28.626058, 'lng': 77.240976}, {'lat': 28.626479, 'lng': 77.241273}, {'lat': 28.627004, 'lng': 77.241164}, {'lat': 28.627185, 'lng': 77.241107}, {'lat': 28.627345, 'lng': 77.240953}, {'lat': 28.627505, 'lng': 77.240714}, {'lat': 28.627632, 'lng': 77.240544}, {'lat': 28.627821, 'lng': 77.240202}, {'lat': 28.628253, 'lng': 77.239422}, {'lat': 28.628806, 'lng': 77.238422}, {'lat': 28.628896, 'lng': 77.238258}, {'lat': 28.630295, 'lng': 77.235864}, {'lat': 28.630725, 'lng': 77.235121}, {'lat': 28.632533, 'lng': 77.231993}, {'lat': 28.632975, 'lng': 77.231229}, {'lat': 28.633687, 'lng': 77.230011}, {'lat': 28.633703, 'lng': 77.229983}, {'lat': 28.635181, 'lng': 77.227409}, {'lat': 28.63596, 'lng': 77.226052}, {'lat': 28.636794, 'lng': 77.2246}, {'lat': 28.637572, 'lng': 77.223245}, {'lat': 28.637722, 'lng': 77.223276}, {'lat': 28.637944, 'lng': 77.223315}, {'lat': 28.638846, 'lng': 77.223373}, {'lat': 28.639651, 'lng': 77.223424}, {'lat': 28.64072, 'lng': 77.223516}, {'lat': 28.641643, 'lng': 77.223595}, {'lat': 28.64176, 'lng': 77.223605}, {'lat': 28.643471, 'lng': 77.223752}, {'lat': 28.643652, 'lng': 77.223768}, {'lat': 28.644405, 'lng': 77.223788}, {'lat': 28.644645, 'lng': 77.223721}, {'lat': 28.645199, 'lng': 77.223614}, {'lat': 28.645263, 'lng': 77.224168}, {'lat': 28.645312, 'lng': 77.224548}, {'lat': 28.645305, 'lng': 77.224707}, {'lat': 28.645628, 'lng': 77.224469}, {'lat': 28.645894, 'lng': 77.224703}, {'lat': 28.645554, 'lng': 77.225311}, {'lat': 28.645318, 'lng': 77.225732}, {'lat': 28.644866, 'lng': 77.226539}, {'lat': 28.644096, 'lng': 77.228079}, {'lat': 28.643838, 'lng': 77.227898}, {'lat': 28.643824, 'lng': 77.227921}, {'lat': 28.643809, 'lng': 77.227942}, {'lat': 28.643791, 'lng': 77.227961}, {'lat': 28.643771, 'lng': 77.227976}, {'lat': 28.64375, 'lng': 77.227989}, {'lat': 28.643727, 'lng': 77.227999}, {'lat': 28.643704, 'lng': 77.228005}, {'lat': 28.64368, 'lng': 77.228007}, {'lat': 28.643657, 'lng': 77.228007}, {'lat': 28.643633, 'lng': 77.228002}, {'lat': 28.64361, 'lng': 77.227994}, {'lat': 28.643592, 'lng': 77.227985}, {'lat': 28.643568, 'lng': 77.227969}, {'lat': 28.643316, 'lng': 77.22859}, {'lat': 28.643238, 'lng': 77.228936}, {'lat': 28.643164, 'lng': 77.229376}, {'lat': 28.642886, 'lng': 77.230104}, {'lat': 28.642637, 'lng': 77.230727}, {'lat': 28.642284, 'lng': 77.232064}, {'lat': 28.642222, 'lng': 77.232308}, {'lat': 28.642151, 'lng': 77.23243}, {'lat': 28.642175, 'lng': 77.232446}, {'lat': 28.642395, 'lng': 77.232579}, {'lat': 28.642494, 'lng': 77.232617}, {'lat': 28.64258, 'lng': 77.232613}, {'lat': 28.642705, 'lng': 77.232863}, {'lat': 28.642683, 'lng': 77.232965}, {'lat': 28.642657, 'lng': 77.233109}, {'lat': 28.642838, 'lng': 77.233235}, {'lat': 28.642947, 'lng': 77.233332}, {'lat': 28.643037, 'lng': 77.233394}, {'lat': 28.643142, 'lng': 77.233464}, {'lat': 28.64306, 'lng': 77.233729}, {'lat': 28.642957, 'lng': 77.234041}, {'lat': 28.642824, 'lng': 77.234399}, {'lat': 28.642832, 'lng': 77.234428}, {'lat': 28.642821, 'lng': 77.234505}, {'lat': 28.642794, 'lng': 77.234614}, {'lat': 28.642776, 'lng': 77.234739}, {'lat': 28.642837, 'lng': 77.234809}, {'lat': 28.642875, 'lng': 77.234869}, {'lat': 28.642911, 'lng': 77.234933}, {'lat': 28.642932, 'lng': 77.235004}, {'lat': 28.642979, 'lng': 77.235239}, {'lat': 28.642994, 'lng': 77.235321}, {'lat': 28.64301, 'lng': 77.235468}, {'lat': 28.643146, 'lng': 77.235464}, {'lat': 28.643361, 'lng': 77.235482}, {'lat': 28.643623, 'lng': 77.235503}, {'lat': 28.644147, 'lng': 77.235528}, {'lat': 28.644133, 'lng': 77.235673}, {'lat': 28.644144, 'lng': 77.235834}, {'lat': 28.644305, 'lng': 77.235889}, {'lat': 28.644524, 'lng': 77.236013}, {'lat': 28.644736, 'lng': 77.236133}, {'lat': 28.644937, 'lng': 77.23627}, {'lat': 28.644989, 'lng': 77.236209}, {'lat': 28.645156, 'lng': 77.236011}, {'lat': 28.645274, 'lng': 77.236121}, {'lat': 28.645461, 'lng': 77.236163}, {'lat': 28.645693, 'lng': 77.236191}, {'lat': 28.64592, 'lng': 77.236211}, {'lat': 28.646049, 'lng': 77.236214}, {'lat': 28.64662, 'lng': 77.236226}, {'lat': 28.646623, 'lng': 77.236264}, {'lat': 28.646963, 'lng': 77.236284}, {'lat': 28.647244, 'lng': 77.236302}, {'lat': 28.647433, 'lng': 77.236316}, {'lat': 28.647798, 'lng': 77.236343}, {'lat': 28.648294, 'lng': 77.236381}, {'lat': 28.648265, 'lng': 77.236716}, {'lat': 28.648274, 'lng': 77.237136}, {'lat': 28.64831, 'lng': 77.237483}, {'lat': 28.6484, 'lng': 77.237978}, {'lat': 28.648375, 'lng': 77.238208}, {'lat': 28.648332, 'lng': 77.238262}, {'lat': 28.648332, 'lng': 77.240151}, {'lat': 28.649828, 'lng': 77.239082}, {'lat': 28.650003, 'lng': 77.239422}, {'lat': 28.650161, 'lng': 77.239851}, {'lat': 28.650255, 'lng': 77.240108}, {'lat': 28.650312, 'lng': 77.240668}, {'lat': 28.650322, 'lng': 77.241203}, {'lat': 28.650238, 'lng': 77.242423}, {'lat': 28.650239, 'lng': 77.242528}, {'lat': 28.650241, 'lng': 77.242561}, {'lat': 28.650253, 'lng': 77.243214}, {'lat': 28.650255, 'lng': 77.243303}, {'lat': 28.650256, 'lng': 77.243345}, {'lat': 28.65026, 'lng': 77.243563}, {'lat': 28.650335, 'lng': 77.244032}, {'lat': 28.650419, 'lng': 77.24438}, {'lat': 28.650576, 'lng': 77.244864}, {'lat': 28.650641, 'lng': 77.245065}, {'lat': 28.650663, 'lng': 77.245119}, {'lat': 28.6507, 'lng': 77.245102}, {'lat': 28.650858, 'lng': 77.245027}, {'lat': 28.651111, 'lng': 77.244928}, {'lat': 28.65132, 'lng': 77.244864}, {'lat': 28.651465, 'lng': 77.244826}, {'lat': 28.651617, 'lng': 77.244798}, {'lat': 28.651924, 'lng': 77.244774}, {'lat': 28.652387, 'lng': 77.244804}, {'lat': 28.653574, 'lng': 77.244905}, {'lat': 28.656209, 'lng': 77.245034}, {'lat': 28.657329, 'lng': 77.245111}, {'lat': 28.65765, 'lng': 77.245072}, {'lat': 28.659213, 'lng': 77.243741}, {'lat': 28.659126, 'lng': 77.24404}, {'lat': 28.659104, 'lng': 77.244231}, {'lat': 28.659099, 'lng': 77.244307}, {'lat': 28.659104, 'lng': 77.244391}, {'lat': 28.659117, 'lng': 77.244476}, {'lat': 28.659253, 'lng': 77.244928}, {'lat': 28.659318, 'lng': 77.244752}, {'lat': 28.659359, 'lng': 77.244661}, {'lat': 28.659402, 'lng': 77.244596}, {'lat': 28.65946, 'lng': 77.244535}, {'lat': 28.659716, 'lng': 77.244388}, {'lat': 28.659866, 'lng': 77.244317}, {'lat': 28.660001, 'lng': 77.24427}, {'lat': 28.660114, 'lng': 77.244239}, {'lat': 28.660265, 'lng': 77.244209}, {'lat': 28.660746, 'lng': 77.244128}, {'lat': 28.660787, 'lng': 77.244128}, {'lat': 28.660818, 'lng': 77.244132}, {'lat': 28.660862, 'lng': 77.244149}, {'lat': 28.660897, 'lng': 77.244111}, {'lat': 28.660942, 'lng': 77.244084}, {'lat': 28.661027, 'lng': 77.24406}, {'lat': 28.661212, 'lng': 77.244041}, {'lat': 28.66127, 'lng': 77.244038}, {'lat': 28.661309, 'lng': 77.244034}, {'lat': 28.661358, 'lng': 77.244018}, {'lat': 28.661397, 'lng': 77.243998}, {'lat': 28.661479, 'lng': 77.24395}, {'lat': 28.661535, 'lng': 77.243922}, {'lat': 28.661588, 'lng': 77.243891}, {'lat': 28.661681, 'lng': 77.243854}, {'lat': 28.661792, 'lng': 77.243794}, {'lat': 28.661949, 'lng': 77.243718}, {'lat': 28.662079, 'lng': 77.243665}, {'lat': 28.662381, 'lng': 77.243539}, {'lat': 28.662393, 'lng': 77.243382}, {'lat': 28.662415, 'lng': 77.243109}, {'lat': 28.662428, 'lng': 77.242898}, {'lat': 28.662442, 'lng': 77.242449}, {'lat': 28.662433, 'lng': 77.242232}, {'lat': 28.662449, 'lng': 77.241964}, {'lat': 28.66246, 'lng': 77.241866}, {'lat': 28.662478, 'lng': 77.241788}, {'lat': 28.662505, 'lng': 77.241706}, {'lat': 28.662553, 'lng': 77.24156}, {'lat': 28.662569, 'lng': 77.241462}, {'lat': 28.662572, 'lng': 77.241393}, {'lat': 28.662573, 'lng': 77.241327}, {'lat': 28.662564, 'lng': 77.241268}, {'lat': 28.662559, 'lng': 77.241241}, {'lat': 28.662537, 'lng': 77.241176}, {'lat': 28.662536, 'lng': 77.241174}, {'lat': 28.662597, 'lng': 77.241259}, {'lat': 28.662609, 'lng': 77.241285}, {'lat': 28.662652, 'lng': 77.241379}, {'lat': 28.662681, 'lng': 77.241441}, {'lat': 28.66269, 'lng': 77.241481}, {'lat': 28.662748, 'lng': 77.241731}, {'lat': 28.662763, 'lng': 77.241793}, {'lat': 28.662764, 'lng': 77.241815}, {'lat': 28.662777, 'lng': 77.242034}, {'lat': 28.663038, 'lng': 77.24214}, {'lat': 28.663418, 'lng': 77.242239}, {'lat': 28.663482, 'lng': 77.242256}, {'lat': 28.663141, 'lng': 77.243549}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I read the CSV file into a Pandas' DataFrame, extract the numbers from your boundary column, convert to shapely polygons, convert Pandas df to GeoPandas gdf:

```py
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\GIS\data\testdata\latlongs.txt", sep='\t') #Create a pandas dataframe from the csv

df.boundary = df.boundary.str.findall('\d+\.\d+').apply(lambda x: list(map(float, x))) #Extract numbers from boundary string

def givepoly(col):
    """Function to return a shapely polygon from a string of lat and longs"""
    return Polygon([[col[i+1], col[i]] for i in range(0, len(col)-1,2)])

df['geometry'] = df.apply(lambda row: givepoly(row['boundary']), axis=1)

df2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry='geometry', crs="EPSG:4326")
df2.drop('boundary', inplace=True, axis=1) #A shapefile cant have a list as data type
df2.to_file(r"C:\GIS\data\testdata\latlongs.shp")
```

[image]