# After converting CSV file to polygon, polygons are not falling on correct location

Tags: python, arcpy, coordinate-system, arcgis-pro, geopandas

I have a CSV file with records in below format.

| area | confidence | boundary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 159.1512 | 0.8084 | POLYGON((87.7185491791352 22.5667828312016, 87.7184590804737 22.5667864311825, 87.7184519272495 22.5666320082646, 87.7185420258111 22.5666284082901, 87.7185491791352 22.5667828312016)) |

I am using the following python code which uses the boundary column to get the polygon shapefile from it.The code works fine however, when I add the exported the shapefile into ArcGIS the polygons are not falling on correct location.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

df = pd.read_csv(r"/content/Test_Polygon.csv")

df.boundary = df.boundary.str.findall('\d+\.\d+').apply(lambda x: list(map(float, x))) #Extract numbers from boundary string

def givepoly(col):
    """Function to return a shapely polygon from a string of lat and longs"""
    return Polygon([[col[i+1], col[i]] for i in range(0, len(col)-1,2)])

df['geometry'] = df.apply(lambda row: givepoly(row['boundary']), axis=1)

df2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry='geometry', crs="EPSG:4326")
df2.drop('boundary', inplace=True, axis=1) #A shapefile cant have a list as data type
df2.to_file(r"/content/test3.shp")
```

[image]

Am not sure where am going wrong in this. I used the following link for reference : [Converting CSV file with polygons in dictionary format into GeoDataFrame](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/410838/converting-csv-file-with-polygons-in-dictionary-format-into-geodataframe)

Comment: You have a tag for ArcPy but the code that you've presented does use that module.

Comment: Traditionally the first thing to check is what coordinate order the library or application assumes - lon/lat or lat/lon.

Comment: In this piece of code, it is assumed that the coordinates are referring to EPSG:4326 (WGS84). Are you sure this is the case with your coordinates?

Comment: The comment in the code "Function to return a shapely polygon from a string of lat and longs" but I believe that the geometry is lon-lats from around here https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=5/22.567/87.719.

Comment: @user30184 Yes, after your earlier I comment I paid attention to the order and indeed the file I have contains the order of Long/Lat  whereas code is for Lat/Long order however, am not sure how to fix the code so that it takes Long/Lat order.

Comment: Perhaps the place to look at is this `[[col[i+1], col[i]]`

Comment: Swapping the values worked. @user30184. Thank you for your observation.

Comment: Write the solution as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better solution is to use directly [geopandas.GeoSeries.from_wkt](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.from_wkt.html)

```
 df = pd.read_csv("Test_Polygon.csv")
 print(df.boundary[0])
 POLYGON ((87.7185491791352 22.5667828312016, 87.7184590804737 22.5667864311825, 87.7184519272495 22.5666320082646, 87.7185420258111 22.5666284082901, 87.7185491791352 22.5667828312016))
 import geopandas as gpd
 s = gpd.GeoSeries.from_wkt(df.boundary)
 gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data=df, geometry=s)
 print(gdf.geometry[0])
 POLYGON ((87.7185491791352 22.5667828312016, 87.7184590804737 22.5667864311825, 87.7184519272495 22.5666320082646, 87.7185420258111 22.5666284082901, 87.7185491791352 22.5667828312016))
```

You can also use shapely

```
from shapely import wkt
df["geom"] = gpd.GeoSeries.from_wkt(df["boundary"])
gdf2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry="geom")
print(gdf2.geometry[0])
POLYGON ((87.7185491791352 22.5667828312016, 87.7184590804737 22.5667864311825, 87.7184519272495 22.5666320082646, 87.7185420258111 22.5666284082901, 87.7185491791352 22.5667828312016))
```

or

```
df['geom2']= df.boundary.apply(wkt.loads)
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry='geom2')
print(gdf.geometry[0])
POLYGON ((87.7185491791352 22.5667828312016, 87.7184590804737 22.5667864311825, 87.7184519272495 22.5666320082646, 87.7185420258111 22.5666284082901, 87.7185491791352 22.5667828312016))
```

Answer (score 1):

Swapping the values placed the geometry on correct location. Here's the modified the code:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

df = pd.read_csv(r"/content/Test_Polygon.csv")

df.boundary = df.boundary.str.findall('\d+\.\d+').apply(lambda x: list(map(float, x))) #Extract numbers from boundary string

def givepoly(col):
    """Function to return a shapely polygon from a string of lat and longs"""
    return Polygon([[col[i], col[i + 1]] for i in range(0, len(col)-1,2)])

df['geometry'] = df.apply(lambda row: givepoly(row['boundary']), axis=1)

df2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry='geometry', crs="EPSG:4326")
df2.drop('boundary', inplace=True, axis=1) #A shapefile cant have a list as data type
df2.to_file(r"/content/test3.shp")
```

The only other concern that I have is when I add the shapefile to the map the geometries are displaying at a very small size.

[image]

Am not sure if this is an expected behaviour or code can be fixed so that geometry is displayed at an appropriate scale.

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding the above mentioned code however got the error : TypeError: Expected bytes or string, got list

```
def givepoly(col):
    """Function to return a shapely polygon from a string of lat and longs"""
    return Polygon([[col[i], col[i+1]] for i in range(0, len(col)-1,2)])

df['geometry'] = df.apply(lambda row: givepoly(row['boundary']), axis=1)

s = gpd.GeoSeries.from_wkt(df.boundary)
df2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=s)
df2.drop('boundary', inplace=True, axis=1) #A shapefile cant have a list as data type
df2.to_file(r"/content/test5.shp")
```

Not sure where am I going wrong.